# try to print a map in lwc combobox

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, js, lightning-combobox

i try to pass a string map from apex to js LWC and print that values in a combobox. i follow more answer from here, but dont working on my code. the combobox dont load data.

**apex metod**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String,String> getLocation(){

 
    SObjectField picklistUsingGlobal = SObjectType.CC_Instalacion__c.fields.CC_Provincia__c.getSObjectField();
    List<PicklistEntry> listLocation = picklistUsingGlobal.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
                                        
    System.debug('listLocation: ----------------- ' + listLocation);

    Map<String,String> listLocationLabels = new Map<String,String>();

    for (Integer i=0; i<listLocation.size(); i++ ){
        listLocationLabels.put(listLocation[i].getValue(), listLocation[i].getLabel());
        System.debug('NAME: ----------------- ' + listLocationLabels.values());
    }
       
    return listLocationLabels;
  
}
```

**js wire and get metod**

```
@wire(getLocation)
locationData({error, data}){
    if(data){
        console.log('esto es la info de las ciudades --------> '+ data);
        
        for (let key in data){
            this.locations.push({value:data[key], key:key});
        }
        this.error = error;
    }else if(error){
        this.error = error;
        this.locations = data;
    }

get filtroLocalizacion() {

   return this.locations;

}
```

**and the combobox HTML**

```
<lightning-combobox name="ciudad" label="Ciudad" value={value} placeholder="Selecciona una ciudad"
                            options={filtroLocalizacion} onchange={handleKeyChange}></lightning-combobox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never initializes `locations`, and even if it did, if the data provisions more than once, you'd get duplicate entries. Also, you're using the property names `key` and `value`, but it should be `value` and `label`. Consider doing this instead:

```
this.locations = Object.entries(data).map(([value,label]) => ({ value, label }))
```

`Object.entries(arg0)` returns the key-value pairs as an array of arrays, which we then pass into the map function. The map function transforms an array using some rule, which is defined by a callback function. For the callback function, we use `(...) => ({...})`, which is an arrow function, with parameters on the left and a return object on the right. `([value,label])` is a destructuring statement that takes the array's indices from `Object.entries` and assigns them labels. We then use object short-hand notation to create an object with those properties.

Comment: very thanks, its work!! but i had to change a little think in apex class, I had @auraenable on and I had to change it (cacheable=true). I have a other problem i need the value thats equal to the label and don't know how to do it